# FFMPEG input a lot .ts files with increment

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, m3u8

I'm a newbie in FFMPEG and know a little about streams.
There is a site where I want to get a video stream. There is an m3u8 that contains current .ts stream as the last row. Each .ts file during 6 seconds and has name like a 'media_3482026' where 3482026 is increment each 6 seconds(each chunk).
I think ffmpeg can create names like a 'media_[increment]' for input. How can I do it? Or may be there is any better way?

It's queries(may be it helps)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ffmpeg -i "media_%i.ts" -codec copy media.mp4`

Comment: But my increment starts not from 0. How can I set increment start?